# Google drive API and auth

Tags: authentication, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to create a web app letting any user upload a file to my Google drive and then be able to view it through the browser.
So far looking at Google's examples it seems I have to auth to my Google Drive on the server side (makes sense....) but also end-users have to auth before uploading anything to my drive using Oauth. Is there a way to prevent having to ask users to authenticate prior to uploading documents given that I am authorized through my server to my Google Drive account?

Allowing anyone to view a document is more straightforward through the use of a public folder...